# Check if CSV file empty or not using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find if my csv file is empty or not using vba?
My csv file size is 7kb though it is empty, so through I cannot find out using size function.
Could

Comment: How are we defining "empty" if not 0 bytes?

Comment: Need to read the csv file to check maybe to check if no content

Comment: Where do the 7kb come from?